# Is there a way to bring my validation messages inline

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am very much new to Drupal.
I have achieved the validation message in the form.
Is there any way to change the position of the validation messages to inline.

I tried using $form['#disable_inline_form_errors'], but this didnt worked, is there any file we have to call for using this?

`$form['#attributes']['novalidate'] = '';`
`$form['#disable_inline_form_errors'] = FALSE;`

`$form['name'] = array(`
    `'#type' => 'textfield',`
     `'#title' => t('Name'),`
      `'#required' => TRUE,`
      `'#default_value' => (isset($record['name']) && $_GET['num']) ? $record['name']:'',`
     `);`

`public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {`

```
     ` $name = $form_state->getValue('name');`
      ` if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $name)) {`
         ` $form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('your name must in characters without space'));`
      ` }`
```

`parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);`
  `}`

Comment: Please check on this page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/inline-form-errors/inline-form-errors-module-overview

Comment: Tried, didnt worked, I dont know why.